Poem about the coffee rings left behind on a table
This poem was published in a quarterly poetry magazine in the mid-'90s. It was about the coffee rings left behind on a table in a cafe. The coffee stains were compared to the memories of our lifetime. It may have been a hint to fading memories as the coffee stains also faded, but I can't recall for sure. It was a short poem, not a long essay—definitely less than 30 lines. What was the poem?

Is it this one? https://allpoetry.com/poem/3503536-The-Coffee-Table-by-Gdsmck77
